# Como puedo filtrar por varias categorias de un producto? Laravel Vuejs

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

tengo la siguiente consulta

```
$result = Producto::from('productos as p')
          ->join('categorias as c', 'c.id', '=', 'p.categoria_id')
          ->join('empresas as e', 'e.id', '=', 'p.empresa_id')
          ->join('multimedia_imagenes as mi', 'mi.producto_id', '=', 'p.id')
          ->join('marcas as m', 'm.id', '=', 'p.marca_id')
          ->where('mi.imagen', '<>', '')
          ->whereNotNull('mi.imagen')
          ->where('p.estado', '1')
          ->with('categoria')
          ->where(function ($query) use ($array_categoria) {

              $query->where('c.id', '=', 1);
          })
          ->select('p.*')
          ->orderBy('p.prioridad', 'asc')
          ->groupBy('p.id')
          ->paginate(20);
```

Como se puede ver hay una variable llamada $array_categoria que me trae los id de las categorias que quiero filtrar.
El array llega en este formato `[10, 8, 12, 13]`

Pense en agregar un bucle for dentro de mi condicionante pero no me funciono... 
Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Imaginate que estas viendo una lista de articulos en una tienda... despues solo quieres ver los articulos de la categoria calzados y playeras... Esa es la funcionalidad que busco, que se pueda filtrar por varias categorias

Comment: Me refiero al resultado en números, ¿técnicamente qué intentas hacer?... cada quien puede imaginar una cosa distinta con eso que dices.

Comment: Quiero una lista de productos en donde su id de categoria sea igual a 10 u 8 u 13 o 12,}

Comment: Que se muestren solo los productos que tengan uno de esos id de categoria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si recibes un arreglo de ids, puedes usar whereIn():

```
$query->whereIn('c.id', [10, 8, 12, 13]);
```

Puedes ver más información en la documentación: 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Que genial. muchisimas gracias